# Ionic - On IOS, Stripe payment button is hidden by the keyboard

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, stripe-payments

My app integrates with Stripe for payment purpose, but I have an issue on IOS... People can't pay.

The payment button is hovered over by the keyboard, and there is no button to close it like there is on Android.

I can't succeed into making the popup scroll either.

I'm using [custom integration](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) and didn't find anything to help me... Other than making everything from scratch with a custom modal and custom form. And I really don't want to do that.

[image]

You can see the tiny top line of the blue button under the keyboard... That's what we want to click !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that in a webview?  Stripe doesn't always work the way you'd expect in a webview.  You might need to build your form with [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) rather than [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout).

Comment: That's what I feared... Thanks for your answer. Still hope for someone to shows up with a magical trick from the hat, otherwise I will have to take the longer way.

Answer (score 3):

Install cordova keyboard plugin and in you app.component.ts add this:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  ...
  this.keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false); // Hide the keyboard accessory bar with the next, previous and done buttons.
  ...
});
```

Then when the keyboard show up you will have a nice "Done" option to close it.
This should help your customer to finalize payment.

Comment: This could be a nice way to do it! I replaced Stripe Checkout with Stripe Elements for IOS in the time being, but will definitely try and test your solution in the coming days.

Comment: Works well as a quick fix.  Here is the Capacitor version:
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Keyboard } = Plugins;
...
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      ...
      Keyboard.setAccessoryBarVisible({isVisible: true});
    });