# Stripe Checkout Keyboard hides payment button

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, capacitor

I am using the Stripe check https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js.

It works fine for Angular projects and okish for Ionic on an Android device but on iOS the keyboard blocks the payment button and the user cannot continue.

If the user clicks anywhere else on the screen it does not hide the keyboard.
Also scrolling the form up or down does not work as the Stripe form is fixed in place.

**I am looking to a solution or workaround to allow the user to continue.**

I have tried using Capacitor to setAccessoryBarVisible({isVisible: true}); for the keyboard but this does not work for me on either Android or iOS.
I would prefer not to use Stripe Elements due to time constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:
[Ionic - On IOS, Stripe payment button is hidden by the keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55651617/ionic-on-ios-stripe-payment-button-is-hidden-by-the-keyboard/56490174#56490174)

And then converted to Capacitor:

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Keyboard } = Plugins;
...
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      ...
      Keyboard.setAccessoryBarVisible({isVisible: true});
    });
```